# SUPEE-8788 patch can't be applied

Tags: magento-1.8, security, patches, supee-8788

I am trying to apply the SUPEE-8788 (PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.8.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-35-11.sh) on a Magento 1.8.1.0 installation.

However when I run it I get a:

```
./PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.8.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-35-11.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

Here is my `applied.patches.list` content:

```
cat app/etc/applied.patches.list
2016-03-16 10:39:55 UTC | SUPEE-1049 | EE_1.12.0.2 | v1 | 5cd884653325315804056d4c591572385b3c1d03 | Thu Mar 20 16:33:19 2014 +0200 | v1.12.0.2..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php
patching file js/prototype/validation.js
Hunk #1 succeeded at 710 (offset 42 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 892 (offset 42 lines).


2016-03-16 10:54:34 UTC | SUPEE-1533 | EE_1.13 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13_v1.patch
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php


2016-03-16 10:56:01 UTC | SUPEE-2747 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v1 | 5b7ff40ed56add4988dbf03f661f844f47ab140f | Tue Jan 14 18:36:41 2014 +0200 | v1.13.1.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php


2016-03-16 10:58:03 UTC | SUPEE-3941 | EE_1.14.0.1 | v1 | d35110621d80be22922611e2b0a502da054a95f0 | Tue Jul 15 11:57:57 2014 +0300 | v1.14.0.1..HEAD
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Backup.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Singleconfig.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Validator.php
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml


2016-03-16 11:00:43 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | Thu Feb 5 19:14:49 2015 +0200 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 537 (offset -4 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
patching file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php


2016-03-16 11:01:39 UTC | SUPEE-5994 | CE_1.6.0.0 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1.patch
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
patching file get.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php


2016-03-16 11:04:51 UTC | SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.8.1.0 | v1 | b2fac29e26174150c655a15a6aae41634cb4420f | Tue Jun 23 08:57:53 2015 +0300 | 76d0bc3c0b..b2fac29e26
patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php


2016-03-16 11:07:07 UTC | SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.9.2.0 | v1 |  | Tue Jul 14 14:17:04 2015 +0300 |
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 209 (offset -24 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php


2016-03-16 11:08:20 UTC | SUPEE-6788 | CE_1.8.1.0 | v1 | 854766736b694382a6c5ad5d64327c32fb26f0b9 | Fri Oct 23 13:52:50 2015 +0300 | 4263b8c
patching file .htaccess
Hunk #1 succeeded at 284 (offset 77 lines).
patching file .htaccess.sample
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Soap/Server.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Exception.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
patching file cron.php
patching file errors/processor.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php


2016-03-16 11:12:42 UTC | SUPEE-7405-CE-1-8-1-0 | CE_1.8.1.0 | v1 | 7b9c8a8353510903624d8d9ce11b982811dd0df5 | Tue Jan 19 16:00:28 2016 +0200 | 854766736b..7b9c8a8353
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php


2016-03-16 11:14:59 UTC | SUPEE-7405 | CE_1.8.1.0 | v1.1 | 7abc9e2aeabfd6fe2adb9ec5aeaa1338e3100178 | Fri Feb 5 13:26:33 2016 +0200 | 7b9c8a8353510903624d8d9ce11b982811dd0df5..7abc9e2aeabfd6fe2adb9ec5aeaa1338e3100178
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

What should I do to correctly apply it?

---

UPDATE

I reverted 1533 as suggested (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html).

```
Apply SUPEE-8788
To apply patch SUPEE-8788:

Open <your Magento install dir>/app/etc/applied.patches.list in a text editor.
Verify SUPEE-8788 is not applied. If it is, and it's version 1, see Replace SUPEE-8788 version 1 with version 2.
Verify whether or not patch SUPEE-1533 is applied. If it is, and your Magento version is earlier than EE 1.14.1.0 or CE 1.9.1.0, revert SUPEE-1533.
If your Magento version is earlier than EE 1.14.1.0 or CE 1.9.1.0, and SUPEE-3941 is not applied, apply SUPEE-3941.
Get version 2 of SUPEE-8788.
Apply version 2 of SUPEE-8788.
```

Now in my applied.patches.list was appended:

```
2016-10-17 08:20:28 UTC | SUPEE-1533 | EE_1.13 | v1 | _ | n/a | SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13_v1.patch | REVERTED
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
```

However I still have problems (but less than before).
Here's its output:

```
./PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.8.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-35-11.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design/Images.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design.phtml
checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
checking file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
```

Comment: zipping the patch before uploading it via ftp and then unzipping it on the server solved the issue, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going well with:

1. opening the patch, remove the complete start (everything except the patch), so until **PATCH_FILE_STARTS** (or something alike)
2. Renaming it to *.patch
3. put it in magento directory
4. Right click in PHPStorm: (Apply patch)

The problem I had is, that it seems that some patches are already applied (I used the first version of 8788!) and my impression is, that the conflict management of the patch tool of PHPStorm is very advanced compared to `patch`

Comment: It seems to me more like a workaround... can you describe me a little why should I do the steps described? is there a problem with my configuration / file permissions)

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I can see you still got 1533 applied that's what the issue is. With the new v2 of the patch here's the procedure to follow:

[image: -]

Comment: Ok I'll try that first. From my understanding, since I have not installed v1, I believed that I shouldn't do any of the thing written there...

Comment: @NikoZarzani you don't have to revert SUPEE-8788 v1 as you haven't installed it. But you still need to revert 1533 and install 3941 before installing 8788 v2

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism 
I am using magento 1.9.1.0. I was revert the 1533 patches successfully. after i was tried to install 8788version 2. till i have error 1) checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController‌​.php Hunk #1 FAILED at 91. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED 2)checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php Hunk #1 FAILED at 34 (different line endings). 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED 3)checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php Hunk #1 FAILED at 101 (different line endings). 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED

Comment: 4) checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php Hunk #1 FAILED at 84 (different line endings). 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED getting above 4 errors on prompt. please guide me or help @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Comment: there should be a problem @Crock

Comment: there should be a problem with the file you mentioned @Crock , sometimes when you load file via ftp it can create a mismatch with the patched one. Try zipping the file form a brand new magento folder and then unzipping it on server and replace it. Hope it helps.