# SUPEE-8788 (V2) patch is not install on magento 1.8.1.0 version

Tags: magento-1.8

When we install SUPEE-8788 (V2) patch on magento 1.8.1.0 version then shows

```
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php.rej
```

We have install previously 7405 patch on my site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [common issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140560/22860). In order to apply SUPEE-8788, you'll first have to revert SUPEE-1533 (`sh SUPEE-1533-PATCH-FILE-NAME.sh -R`) and make sure you have SUPEE-3941 installed, see [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141141/22860) for more details.